# Create folders for specific items in table

Tags: bash

I have data organized in a table (text tab delimited) as bellow:

```
NAME      TIME          ID        DATE 
--------
John        03:25:01    A10A      2015/05/12
Marry       01:01:15    N000M     2013/01/01
.
.
.
.
```

How can I create folders for every name in this table? Also how can I name the folders as the ID and time only as follow:

```
For John the created folder name is A10A-032501
For Marry the created folder name is N000M-010115
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
tail -n+3 file | while IFS=$'\t' read -r name time id date; do mkdir "$id-${time//:/}"; done
```

After this is run, the following directories will have been created:

```
$ ls -d */
A10A-032501/  N000M-010115/
```

#### Multiple line version

Some prefer their shell code split over multiple lines:

```
tail -n+3 file | while IFS=$'\t' read -r name time id date
do
    mkdir "$id-${time//:/}"
done
```

#### How it works

- `tail -n+3 file`

  This sends the `file` to stdout after removing the two header lines.
- `while IFS=$'\t' read -r name time id date; do`

  This starts a loop over the lines in `file`.  Using a tab as the separator, `IFS=$'\t'`, the four columns are read into the variables `name`, `time`, `id`, and `date`.
- `mkdir "$id-${time//:/}"`

  This creates the directories.  `${time//:/}` removes the colons from the time field.
- `done`

  This marks the end of the loop.

Comment: if the data in the files organized as table but they were written without using a tab as the separator. how can we convert them to tab delimited files?

Comment: If some columns have spaces inside them, not as column-separators, then you are in trouble.  If not, the conversion from space-separated to tab-separated can be done simply with `sed 's/[[:blank:]][[:blank:]]*/\t/g' inputfile >outputfile`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the data lies in 'data.tsv':

`sed -e '1,2d' data.tsv | while read myN myT myI myD; do mkdir $myI-${myT//:/} ; done`

Explanation:
sed runs the "-e"xpression "d"elete lines "1,2" on file data.tsv

None of your examples included a space in the values, so i did not redefine IFS.

The rest is a standard while-loop.